# Executing a string as a command in bash that contains pipes

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to list some ftp directories. I can't work out how to make bash execute a command that contains pipes correctly.

Here's my script:

```
#/bin/sh

declare -a dirs=("/dir1" "/dir2")           # ... and lots more
for d in "${dirs[@]}"
do
    cmd='echo "ls /mydir/'"$d"'/*.tar*" | sftp -b - -i ~/mykey user@example.com 2>&1 | tail -n1'
    $cmd
done
```

This just outputs:

```
"ls /mydir/dir1/*.tar*" | sftp -b - -i ~/mykey user@example.com 2>&1 | tail -n1
"ls /mydir/dir2/*.tar*" | sftp -b - -i ~/mykey user@example.com 2>&1 | tail -n1
```

How can I make bash execute the whole string including the echo? I also need to be able to parse the output of the command.

Comment: Try with using `eval $cmd`.

Comment: Don't do that. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: As an aside, `#!/bin/sh` is wrong when your script uses arrays or other Bash-only features. You want `#!/bin/bash` (or whatever the correct path is on your platform).

Comment: @tripleee eval works for now and this is a quick-and-dirty script so it's good enough. thanks for the shebang pointer.

Comment: @jbrown have you tried my solution? I'm interested to know whether it works.

Comment: Why are you storing the command in a string in the first place? It just complicates your code for no good reason.

Comment: @chepner because I'm not very good at bash

Comment: @jbrown, `eval` "works", but it's dangerous. Using a function to store the definition (as per BashFAQ #50) would be far safer, and, well, why knowingly do things the wrong way?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that you need to be using the `-b` switch at all. It should be sufficient to specify the commands that you would like to execute as a string:

```
#/bin/bash

dirs=("/dir1" "/dir2")
for d in "${dirs[@]}"
do
    printf -v d_str '%q' "$d"
    sftp -i ~/mykey user@example.com "ls /mydir/$d_str/*.tar*" 2>&1 | tail -n1       
done
```

As suggested in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25662841/executing-a-string-as-a-command-in-bash-that-contains-pipes/25663532?noredirect=1#comment40114781_25663532) (thanks @Charles), I've used `printf` with the `%q` format specifier to protect against characters in the directory name that may be interpreted by the shell.

Comment: You should probably quote the wildcards so as to not get a surprise when a glob gets expanded locally.

Comment: This doesn't work. The '-b' option indicates a batch file containing commands to execute on the remote server. '-b -' lets it take the command from stdin. Therefore I echo the command to be executed remotely and pipe it into sftp. It's a kludge but that's how sftp works (at least on OSX).

Comment: @TomFenech No, it still doesn't work. I've solved this anyway. But you really do have to "echo 'ls /the/path' | sftp -b - ...". The only alternative I'm aware of is putting 'ls /the/path' in 'myfile' and calling sftp with 'sftp -b myfile ...'. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @jbrown looking at the manual I don't think that you need to be using the `-b` switch at all. I have edited my answer.

Comment: printf -v d_str '%q' "$d";` then, `sftp ... "ls /mydir/$d_str/*.tar*"` if you want to work correctly with directory names containing literal doublequote symbols, literal `$()` strings, literal backticks, or the like.

Comment: @Charles thanks, I hadn't thought of that. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to use `/bin/bash` as shebang to use BASH arrays.

Then remove echo and use command substitution to capture the output:

```
#/bin/bash

declare -a dirs=("/dir1" "/dir2")           # ... and lots more
for d in "${dirs[@]}"
do
    output=$(ls /mydir/"$d"/*.tar* | sftp -b - -i ~/mykey user@example.com 2>&1 | tail -n1)
    echo "$output"
done
```

I will however advise you not use `ls`'s output in `sftp` command. You can replace that with:

```
output=$(echo "/mydir/$d/"*.tar* | sftp -b - -i ~/mykey user@example.com 2>&1 | tail -n1)
```

Comment: I'm not using 'ls's output with sftp. I'm echoing an ls command to sftp. The exact command I'm trying to script is: echo "ls /mydir/dir1/*.tar*" | sftp -b - -i ~/mykey user@example.com 2>&1 | tail -n1

Comment: Yes I understand that and if you see my first solution I kept your `ls` command there. However if your file names contain space/new lines then it can create problems.

Comment: This doesn't work. It's trying to 'ls' on my machine and then pipe the output to sftp, instead of sending the ls command to sftp to be executed remotely. Anyway, eval works so I've got a solution. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @jbrown, eval "works"; mind the scare quotes. If someone wanted to generate a filename that would cause your eval-based "solution" to do something evil/nasty, that's not so hard to do. Mind you, it's not just intentional attacks you need to worry about -- I've seen TB of backups deleted on account of sloppy scripting practices and a buffer overflow bug putting `" * "` into a filename that was expected to only ever match `^[a-z0-9]+$`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't store the command in a string; just use it directly.

```
#/bin/bash

declare -a dirs=("/dir1" "/dir2")           # ... and lots more
for d in "${dirs[@]}"
do
  echo "ls /mydir/$d/*.tar*" | sftp -b - -i ~/mykey user@example.com 2>&1 | tail -n1
done
```

Usually, people store the command in a string so they can both execute it and log it, as a misguided form of factoring. (I'm of the opinion that it's not worth the trouble required to do correctly.)

Note that `sftp` reads from standard input by default, so you can just use

```
echo "ls ..." | sftp -i ~/mykey user@example.com 2>&1 | tail -n1
```

You can also use a here document instead of a pipeline.

```
sftp -i ~/mykey user@example.com 2>&1 <<EOF | tail -n1
ls /mydir/$d/*.tar.*
EOF
```

Comment: Actually I think it's even simpler than that. I don't think that the `-b` is necessary at all.

Comment: I just read the `sftp` docs; I agree, the `-b` is only needed if you want to read from a file other than standard input.